# F-distribution of data in Matlab

Tags: statistical-significance, data-visualization, matlab, threshold, f-distribution

I have F = 1x44100 vector in Matlab. Based on how this was calculated, we have predicted that this fits the F-distribution with 16 degrees of freedom for both numerator and denominator.

I am really really new to doing anything with distributions, the first thing I am trying to do is

f = fcdf(F,16,16)
and

f1 = fpdf(F,16,16)
Now I am trying to visualise this so that I can see what it looks like and overlap it with the F distribution for the same number of degrees of freedom. For this I do:

x = 0:0.05:2
y = fpdf(x,16,16)
figure;
plot(x,y)
But when I try to overlay this with the plot of f1 it gives me something very strange...

I am basically just trying to overlay the F-distribution of my data over the actual distribution... Once I verify that my data does follow the F-distribution (which it should) then I need to look at the corresponding values for 2.5% and do a significance test to threshold my data.

I am very confused and I am not even sure if what I'm doing is right... Can anyone help please? Or have advice for something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are slightly confused about what will you actually plot. When you visualise your data to compare them against a theoretical distribution you want to have some sort of empirical estimate for your data to begin with. A standard thing to consider is a [kernel density estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) (KDE); you can get those using the function `ksdensity` in MATLAB.
After you obtain the KDE of your data you then overlay the "real" [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) (PDF) estimates above them. The later can be given by simple evaluating the PDF over the space spanned by your sample; you can use the function `pdf` or `fpdf` in MATLAB to get those. At first instance because the F-distribution is continuous you can use as standard [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) to test if your data come from an F-distribution. Please see the following code for a quick example.

(Note: For the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test I just did a quick two sample comparison (`kstest2`). MATLAB allows you to define a distribution object (in this case a F-distribution) using `makedist` if you want to used the one-sample K-S test (`kstest`) against a non-normal distribution; you can ask about the use of that particular MATLAB functionality in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), as it is purely a programming question.)

```
% Set the seed to have some reproducibility
rng(1234); 
F = random('f',16,16, [210^2, 1]);  % Generate data from your distribution
ksdensity(F, 'support', 'positive'); % Plot KDE (defining positive support)
hold on                            
x = linspace(min(F), max(F), 1000); % Define the support of your theoretical plot
plot(x, pdf('f',x, 16,16), 'r' ); % Plot the "real" PDF
```

[image]

```
[h,p] = kstest2(F, random('f',16,16, [2^12,1]) )
% h = 0  % Fails to rejects the null hypothesis at default alpha = 0.05
% p = 0.694370575893602
[h,p] = kstest2(F, random('t',1, 2^12,1])) 
% h = 1  % Succeeds to rejects the null hypothesis at default alpha = 0.05
% p = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I think its clearer now... I didn't understand the kernel density estimator before so I wasn't using that... or more I didn't really understand how to use it. I have one question though... `F = random('f',16,16, [210^2, 1]);` in this line you have generated a sample from the f-distribution... But I already have an array that I think follows the F-distribution, say K2. Then do I just skip this and say `ksdensity(K2, 'support', 'positive');` ? When I do that the KDE and theoretical PDF are not the same/aligned as they are in your plot...

Comment: I think this was happening because I didn't specify with ksdensity that I wanted to plot the PDF thats why it didn't turn out right. I just plotted the CDF of my data's KDE against theoretical CDF of f-distribution spanning the same x space and its turned out decent. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad I could help. Yes, you can skip that line. I just did that for illustration purposes. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using MATLAB's `histogram` function or `histcounts` function. You can plug your matrix F into the function, and it will get you histogram edges and counts. Next, you'll calculate the theoretical values for these edges based on F-distribution. Then you simply draw two histograms.

If you want to make it in Monte Carlo style, then simply generate 44100 values from your theoretical F-distribution into another array F1, then call histogram on both tables using `hold on` in between to overlay the charts.

Comment: For some reason when I try to use histogram it says `Undefined function 'histogram' for input arguments of type 'double'`